# Compile your Overleaf project OFFLINE

Tags: compiling, overleaf

This is a continuation of the question asked by Giacomo Marchioro in [What are the steps for compiling Overleaf projects offline and getting consistent results?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518564/what-are-the-steps-for-compiling-overleaf-projects-offline-and-getting-consisten)

Indeed I have an Overleaf project which I want to compile offline. My project contains no errors in Overleaf. 
In the project files, I've got output.tex file as my main document, latexmkrc file (copy/paste from https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_does_Overleaf_compile_my_project%3F) and the different.tex files and images that form my project are located in folders.

I installed TexLive 2018 from: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html
However, compiler `latexmk -pdf` does not appear.

I tried in TexStudio and it does not compile either. It does not find tables or documents which are placed inside two folders as for instance: Figures\Introduction\Figure_1.PNG

I need to send my project to the jury and I am a bit desperate!
I would greatly appreciate any help telling me how to do it or what I am missing in my code, compiler, installation... to make it work!

Comment: With the information you've given it will be very hard to help you I think. When you say "compiler `latexmk` doesn't appear" what do you mean? If you open an command line window and type `latexmk --help` what happens? Can you create a minimal document that shows the problem you're having with including files. The example you give is a graphics file so I'm assuming you're using `\includegraphics` to include it. But you also mention other files like "table or documents". How are you including these into your file?

Comment: you have not shown any input nor shown what errors you got in the log, so how can anyone tell you what to change?

Comment: Sorry. The document is very long and it would be hard to post all the configuration I have in it.
Thank you very much in any case!

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered the way to compile an Overleaf project with no problems, so I will answer to my own question in case someone can take advantage of it.

With a Mac and TexShop, using the compiler `pdflatexmk` works fine for the compilation. References, index and everything compiles perfectly :)
Of course, making sure your project contains the `latexmkrc` file mentionned in the question above and no errors.