# Using an Overleaf PhD template offline: how?

Tags: overleaf, texniccenter, cls

I would like to use [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-aberdeen-thesis-template/jzrbyqmggygd) from Overleaf for a PhD dissertation at the University of Aberdeen, offline on TeXnicCenter. (This appears to be a legitimate thing, according to my supervisor.)

I have looked at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531328/compile-your-overleaf-project-offline); it didn't help.

My main issue is that I'm not sure how to use the cls file. There might be other problems once that is sorted, so if you could explain to me how to do it, please, I would be most appreciative.

I'm not sure what I can offer in terms of context. But here:

- I did both my MMath and my MPhil dissertations using TeXnicCenter, along with much smaller projects, so I have a fair amount of experience with it.
- Like I said, I think the issue is with the cls file. I believe it is something like a package, but one that I have to install myself - I don't know . . .

*I am likely to award a bounty to the first answer that works when I try it!*

Comment: You simply click on the leaf icon and download the source code of the project. You will get a zip file. Extract it and open the main .tex file with you preferred editor.

Comment: And leave the cls file in the same directory as the main tex file.

Comment: As long as the `.cls` file (and the associated image files) are in the same folder as your main `.tex` file the class will just work. For something like a thesis is the simplest solution. There's no real need to "install" anything. @Sigur Maybe just make this an answer including my comment as well?

Comment: The answer describes leaving the class file in the directory: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197070/107497. Other answers on the page give other possibilities.

Comment: @AlanMunn, done.

Comment: Note: something (pleasant) has come up just now in my private life. I won't be able to try any answers for good few hours, or maybe even until tomorrow. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1: "Open as Template"

[image]

### 2: "Menu"

[image]

### 3: Download "Source"##

[image]

### 4: Locate Downloaded Zip File and Unpack It##

[image]

### 5: Edit (B) "abdnthesis.tex" and Make Sure You Keep (A) "abdnthesis.cls" in the Root Directory (= where "abdnthesis.tex" is Located)##

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You simply click on the leaf icon and download the source code of the project. You will get a zip file. Extract it and open the main `.tex` file with you preferred editor.

As said by @Alan Munn:

> As long as the `.cls` file (and the associated image files) are in the
> same folder as your main `.tex` file the class will just work. For
> something like a thesis is the simplest solution. There's no real need
> to "install" anything.